# Scope of javascript functions in XSL sheet

Tags: javascript, xslt

I need to calculate values for each row of data in XML file. I thought it would be painless, but it isn't. All I get from firefox is that my function isn't defined. This file isn't loaded from server, it's static and I apply an XSL to it statically, too. Using HTML I would do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcVal(price, qty){
    var valIs = 0;
    valIs = price * qty;
    return valIs;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Value is: <script type="text/javascript">document.write(calcVal(100,2.6));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put that in XSL sheet, function is not defined when called in `<body>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<xsl:comment>
<![CDATA[
  function calcVal(price, qty){
    var valIs = 0;
    valIs = price * qty;
    return valIs;
  }
]]>
</xsl:comment>
</script>
</head>
<body>
Value is: <script type="text/javascript">document.write(calcVal(100,2.6));</script>
</body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: I've tried without CDATA, putting SCRIPT tag inside of XSL:COMMENT, without XSL:COMMENT, too, and so on, all variations I could think of.

I need to execute this function multiple times for each row of data, so question is **how do I make this function available in the remaining part of XSL**?

**EDIT** I should add that IE11 calculates this value, in this state of my XSL.

Comment: You can't use `document.write` with XSLT generated HTML in Mozilla browsers (like Firefox) as the Gecko engine they use and its XSLT processor directly creates the HTML result tree and renders it, there is no way to inject pieces of markup with `document.write`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F.

Comment: So in other words, I should write some 'wrapper' html page with required js functions, load XML, then apply XSLT, then calculate on e.g. document.ready? I'll check if that works in a bit.

Comment: I would first check whether the computation can't simply be implemented in pure XSLT. If not, then of course instead of document.writing stuff you can always use the DOM API to create text nodes or element nodes and appendChild or insertBefore them, only document.write is not supported.

Comment: OMG, I started today with XSLT, I followed w3schools tutorial and assumed that was it (they didn't mention anything about computation). I actually could perform my simple calculations in pure XSLT. Thanks, Martin Honnen.

Comment: You're looking at something as simple as `Value is: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(100 * 2.6, '#,##0.00')" />`

Comment: Yeah, I have completed my work with stylesheet for this particular document format, and it turned out I could do alot more than just simple calculus with xslt 1.0. I've also employed recursive function to sum up products of price and quantity at the end. But answer to this question seems to be CAN'T BE DONE (at least with Firefox), but that no longer matters. Martin Honnen might want to turn his first comment into an answer, if he wants some points, it helped me to get on the right track.

Comment: @Kitet, I have written an answer on the document.write problem in mozilla and the alternative to use pure XSLT and XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use document.write with XSLT generated HTML in Mozilla browsers (like Firefox) as the Gecko engine they use and its XSLT processor directly creates the HTML result tree and renders it, there is no way to inject pieces of markup with document.write. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F.
As for your use of Javascript to compute some values in the HTML result of the XSLT transformation, you can do the computations with pure XPath as well and of course then output the computed values with pure XSLT, there is no need to throw in Javascript.